How to skip a dependency?
In my manifest, I specify that I want suitesparse. It has a dependency lapack, and another package (not even sure which) has a dependency openblas.
These two dependencies are installed and their libraries are added to my project without making a pip. I don't want them since I use intel-mkl instead.
Another scenario, cgal installs and sets boost without a pip. It decides on a version, and I can't override it.
How do I tell vcpkg to just install a library without its dependencies?
